# Nginx: error_page on root path

Tags: nginx

I have these config in my server block:

```
proxy_intercept_errors on;
error_page 502 =503 /500.html;
error_page 503 =503 /503.html;

location / {

    try_files   $uri $uri/ @node;
    error_page  403 = @node;

}
```

From my testing, it appear to work for most path, except http://domain.com/ itself.

I knew of `recursive_error_pages` but isn't sure about enabling it, is there any gotcha like infinite loop i need to look out for? Or should I modify `error_page` in the location block instead?

My location block basically tell nginx to handle both file and directory, but redirect directory path to upstream if it doesn't have a default index file.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like using [`recursive_error_pages`](http://nginx.org/r/recursive_error_pages) should be completely safe, because there is still a limit of 10 internal redirects per request.